# Capacitor discharge question

Tags: capacitor, discharge

Could I use an incandescent/tungsten AC light bulb to discharge a main 400V capacitor in an SMPS?

Comment: Is it rated to handle 400 volts? Or, just let the load on the output do this for you.

Comment: The capacitor is a main DC cap after the bridge rectifier. Its rated at 350V. Checking with my meter it has 311v on it. Can i use a ac 240v lightbulb to discharge it? Thanks for answering andy

Comment: @LoftInsulation It depends. A lightbulb has very low resistance. Not a direct short circuit but still. What kind of safe currents you want to be limiting the discharge current?

Comment: What value is the capacitor? And, I'm still asking why not "let the load on the output do this for you"?

Comment: I cant mate the smps doesnt work im gonna repair it. I just got the capacitor blocking me to do this

Comment: Use two 230 V ones in series.

Comment: A 230V(RMS) lightbulb regularly sees 320V peak in normal operation. Whilst I’d normally use a resistor to discharge capacitors, a lightbulb would work at a pinch. Why have you not tried it already?  The worst case is the lightbulb could fail, but that is not a  high cost problem. I’d also suggest you wear eye protection when working on such power supplies as they tend to have a habit of going ‘pop’ and ejecting shards of epoxy and arcs.

Comment: Cheers kartman. Cheers , you made my day.  If i leave my tv off for a day, would the capacitor automatically drain itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but the problem in this case is high current consumption.

It would be unlikely to find lightbulbs smaller than 1 watt. For a SMPS, 1 watt idle power consumption is a very big deal. Most good SMPSs achieve maybe less than third of that: for example I haven't found any mobile phone USB charger to consume more than a watt.

I instead recommend a resistor. Let's say you have 4700 µF capacitor. At 311 V, it's 1.46 Coulombs or ampere-seconds. A 1 megaohm resistor at that voltage would create less than 0.1 watts of idle power consumption, and would discharge that capacitor to an acceptable voltage (safe to touch) in few hours. Of course it will never be fully discharged since it's an exponential process, but should be safe to touch in few hours. If the capacitor is smaller, let's say 470 µF, it would discharge in one tenth of that time, i.e. a fraction of an hour.

If this on the other hand is a one-time event, you have some SMPS and you want to discharge its capacitor only once, just touch both leads with a screwdriver (a safely insulated one rated for mains voltages, don't make the mistake of electrocuting yourself!). You don't need any resistor or a light bulb.

Comment: Yes thanks for your reply. Very much appreciate this. My lightbulb is a 60 watt 240 volt tungsten one. Will this be okay? As the wattage is high. Please let me know. I dont like screwdriver method

Comment: The lightbulb would be safer than a screwdriver, but you must still be careful about insulating your hand, body.

Comment: Ah right thanks. Would it damage the light bulb though? Please tell me. Thanl you @glen_geek

Comment: Should not damage a 220V incandescent filament bulb. Discharge will be very fast...ensure that the supply is turned off and power plug is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks mate, but wouldnt using a lightbulb be the same as a resistor? As light bulbs have 10's of ohms.   At normal temperature it could be around 200 ohms

Comment: I’d use a resistor in preference.  A few k ohms will discharge to a safe level quite quickly and at moderate current.  Consider 10k and a 1000uF cap, initial power will be 10W and off the top of my head will drop 30V per second.  I’d use at least a 10W resistor or maybe 10 in series, 1k 1W each

Comment: Yeah thanks frog. Dont have much resistors on me atm. What other method can be used instead of screwdriver or resistor.. cheers